# display time clock according time on laptop with laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a simple website made with PHP and framework Laravel. Now I want to just display the date not the clock time and when I am posting my article on my website it will display the time and date according to the clock on the laptop. how do I do this? any references?

this is my code:

```
<h6 class="date-comments"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ ucwords($article->user->name) }} &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ date('d M Y', strtotime($article->created_at)) }} <i class="fa fa-comments"> {{ count($count) }}</i></h6>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Carbon class is inherited from the PHP DateTime class.

```
use Carbon\Carbon
```

> Carbon has all of the functions inherited from the base DateTime class. This approach allows you to access the base functionality if you see anything missing in Carbon but is there in DateTime.

`class Carbon extends \DateTime
{
    // code here
}`

> Special care has been taken to ensure timezones are handled correctly, and where appropriate are based on the underlying DateTime implementation. For example all comparisons are done in UTC or in the timezone of the datetime being used.

```
$dtToronto = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'America/Toronto');
$dtVancouver = Carbon::create(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'America/Vancouver')

echo $dtVancouver->diffInHours($dtToronto); // 3
```

[Read full Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Make use laravel utility method `toDateString()`.Check the below code.

```
<h6 class="date-comments"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ ucwords($article->user->name) }} &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{ date('d M Y', strtotime($article->created_at->toDateString())) }} <i class="fa fa-comments"> {{ count($count) }}</i></h6>
```